# Is there a way to expose additional fields to the Bulk Action > Edit functionality?

Tags: actions, bulk

I would like to know if it's possible (using the existing WordPress core development features) to hook into the existing WP `Bulk Action` > `Edit` functionality, in order to expose additional fields to the edit action?

I sometimes come across plug-ins that create custom post types, and related custom fields, and then they fail to include most of the custom fields to Wordpress's built in `Bulk Action` > `Edit`. For example, perhaps the most glaring example I've come across is the `Coupons` post type in WooCommerce. Essentially, the Bulk Edit exposes no Coupon fields at all. So the user is left having to edit them one-by-one.

Is there a way, more or less using existing WordPress core development features, to hook into the bulk edit functionality and give it access to more fields?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search yielded these results for me:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpresss-bulk-edit/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-bulkquick-edit/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/bulk-edit/

I am sure there is a way, but I do not think that there is a WP API for that (like options API or transients API, etc...). Maybe you can see what these free plugins are doing and how.

**Edit:**

I found the tutorials you need. Here are the links:

https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/quick-edit-tutorial.html

https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/bulk-edit.html

Comment: sorry but "go look how plugins were written" is not an actual answer.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for input. I'd actually not found those plug-ins in my fairly extensive search for answers. Perhaps because I was looking for articles and tutorials, plug-ins didn't show up in my search. I will, however, take a look at these, although ideally I'd like to hear from someone with the necessary development experience to say one way or the other if this is possible, and to point me in the right direction to figure out how.

Comment: @omega33 I found the tutorials you have been looking for. Hopefully, I am not too late. The tutorials are newer than your question. Anyway, I hope this helps you now. :D